# array value for a dom element in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, checkbox, hidden

Context:
I want to pass a string of checkbox ids as an array to the id of a hidden dom element. Then retrieve the array of values from the hidden dom element and enable the checkboxes based on the earlier retrieved checkbox ids.

This works for a single checkbox id but not for an array. 
Example:

```
var selectedCheckBoxIds =[22,23,24];
$('#<input type="hidden" id="checkboxTasks" value='+selectedCheckBoxIds+'/>');
```

And when I do,

```
var retrieveCheckBoxArray=$('#checkboxTasks').attr('value');
```

I get an empty string for the retrieveCheckBoxArray variable.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
var selectedCheckBoxIds = [22, 23, 24];

// Set the value
$('#checkboxTasks').val(selectedCheckBoxIds);

// Get the value
var retrieveCheckBoxArray = $('#checkboxTasks').val();
```

Comment: Palash, retrieveCheckBoxArray is undefined after the $('#checkboxTasks').val() is assigned.

Comment: I'll have a look again , Palash. Thanks